# Regex obfuscated numbers max length

Tags: regex

So I'm trying to capture numbers with a maximum length of 9, which can be "obfuscated", such as `1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9`, it has a length of 17 but if we "deofuscate" it, it's 9 numbers, so it's a phone number.

I've tried many regex but couldn't find the right one, because there are missing captures and in other cases it captures more than wanted...

(Well this is just a test)
https://regex101.com/r/HmZo1s/1

In this one, it captures correctly the numbers above but not the one below, and it also captures a very long number which must be omitted...
https://regex101.com/r/d9kv8F/1

I hope I've explained correctly what I want to achieve...

And, the number must start with `6, 7 or 9` to be a valid phone number, always 9 digits.

EDIT:
I want to use for phone numbers, but the title is correct, as you might use any kind of number... The "obfuscation pattern" is not always the same, it can be "anything" but of course we won't focus on that, we use "simple" obfuscation (like in the examples above), with dots, slashes and stuff like that.

I think, that the point of this is to "extract" the number, then see if it starts with `6, 7 or 9` and then see if it is 9 digits length, then it is a phone number so we remove it from our text (this is done with a basic replace).

For example

`6.6.6.7.7.7.8.8.8` => `666777888` => `remove`

`5.5.5.4.4.43.3.3` => `555444333` => `not a phone`

this is for a comment based system, in which we want to remove all kind of phones in there, so they won't share them.

Comment: Can you be more exact in what you want to match, and what not? Which intermediate characters do you allow to be removed to recognise a phone number, how many of them at the most, and which characters not? Also, what consists a valid phone number is much more complicated than just checking the first digit is a 6, 7 or 9, and checking the number of digits is 9....

Comment: What about [**`\b[679][-\w. ]{7,15}\d`**](https://regex101.com/r/d9kv8F/2) ?

Comment: *"....a valid phone number"* So this is actually an attempted regex for phone numbers? Your question title, description and examples don't make this at all clear. If you wish to allow the user to input arbitrary text, then I strongly suggest you abandon any attempt to validate it with a regex!

Comment: @TomLord I've updated my question, of course there will be arbitrary text, that's why we need to focus on "simple" obfuscation patterns... I know that sometimes we will miss a hint, but we need to get the most we can without corrupting the full text data...

Answer (score 1):

To **extract** telephone numbers with your desired format, you could come up with:

```
\b[679][-\w. ]{7,15}\d
# \b is a word boundary
# [679] is one of 6, 7 or 9
# followed by dashes, word characters, dots and spaces (7-15 times)
# and a digit in the end
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/d9kv8F/2).

---

***Please note*** that you will still get a lot of false positives (ie `6-------9` which apparently is not a number), so you will very likely have to adjust them programmatically afterwards.

Comment: @sunkuet02: What do you mean here?

Comment: What is about match : 10 and 12 ?

Comment: I do not find the question clear, but the latest update  implies there should be exactly nine digits separated with some separators.

Comment: Yes, it should be exactly nine digits separated with some separators, but as @Jan says, I can check all my matches programmatically afterwards, clearnig all non-digits and checking if it's a real phone (we even have a real phone validation through a mobile company), then we clear the whole match. I find this answer very useful, I don't know why you downvoting it tbh, it does what I asked... I will test against my code and then give updated responses...

Answer (score 0):

what about this one : ([679][^\d]?)(\d[^\d]?){7}\d